# Mixing a film to be viewed on mulitple screens

Tags: mixing, exhibition

Hello sound people. How are we all?

I am going to be working on a short film soon where the director wants to exhibit the film across multiple screens. The film will be approx 6minutes. One idea he had was to have 6 screens each playing a 1minute section of the film on loop. The audience would then have to figure out which part goes where in the film etc. My role is to design sound for his film. Has anyone ever done something like this or anyone with some ideas on the ?

Im thinking of designing the sound for the entire film as it plays (naturally) before chopped into 6parts. Each section or audio would then be cut with the appropriate footage. The audience would then be drawn to 1 screen for 1minute each(i guess helping them know which part of the story is playing). From there it would be up to the director to either play the sections in order or randomly.

What do you think?

Forgot to mention he wants No Dialogue!!

Answer (score 3):

What about doing a Zaireeka?

Zaireeka was an album done by The Flaming Lips. It was 1 record split across 4 CDs.  You had to have 4 stereos and start each CD at exactly the same time to be able to listen to it properly.

Maybe you could try that here.  Build a densely layered 1 minute loop, then split out 6 stems to be played alongside each video loop.  In stead of one piece split into six segments, you'd have six disparate seeming compositions that actually slide together to make a cohesive whole.  Very DaVinci Code.

If you do chop the soundtrack into 1 minute segments, you could try designing them to be perfect loops with no beginning and no end.  That's always a fun challenge and would probably work well against the jumpy cuts that are sure to happen in the video loops.

It'd definitely give you an excuse to go crazy and make as much sound as you can possibly imagine.

Sounds wicked fun for sure.

Comment: @G.A. Wow, zaireeka, that sounds awesome but would be hard to get the four stereos playing at the exact same time..!?one session with 6 stems sounds very interesting though! like an orchestrial piece building one layer at a time until the 6 minute where everything plays together to make an sound anthem!ha.rad! Thanks
 

Answer (score 1):

Wow that sounds interesting, I've never done that. are the screens in different rooms? You might want to feel the room out a bit to know if you need to watch your midrange, also wouldn't hurt to know what kind of system it will be played through. Are the rooms echoey? Things like that.

In general. Yeah, stick with your plan. If I were in your shoes I would mix the film as a full project and then break it up for each screen.

Where is this going to be displayed?

Pete

Comment: @Peter-John. Sure thing, the rooms acoustics will def play a part. I'll check it out. Unsure what the room is like at the moment. From what he has said so far it is going to be a one room audio-visual art exhibition. Where the audience will walk in and be standing watching and listening, free to walk around the room. what do you mean 'where'? what kind of screen? or what part of the room? or which city..? Thanks for your thoughts!